# transpose number to USD

Tags: javascript

I have

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = 
(Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field2').value,2)*100))/100 + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field3').value,2)*100))/100).toFixed(2);"
```

Field 2 and 3 are text input (numeric values). How can I transpose the value of field 1 to a currency value.  Example

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('200.75').value) * parseInt(document.getElementById('11').value);"
```

and have field1 return $2,208.25

Comment: You've asked three questions slowly evolving the same piece of code. What is the end result you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't want to water down one question by asking more than one.  I have a form that takes user numeric input into text fields.  I would like to change that text when the user leaves the field into a USD value (where appropriate) and there are a couple of instances that I calculate for the user (as you could guess).  I would also like to continue the calculation but also transpose these numbers into USD values with $ , .00.  One field has a percentage number put in that I would like to chnage to xx% on user leaving field.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: p.s. this is not from my lack of trying to search through forums or my 1200 page javascript book.

Comment: Robert were you asking from a perspective of willingness to help?